# website with basic http auth and facebook social plugin, twitter button

Tags: facebook, authentication, twitter

I am working on a website on staging environment.
On the staging environment the website uses http basic auth.
And I found that facebook social button and tweet share button won't work if the http basic auth is enabled. Is there any workaround for this? Or should I just disable the http basic auth completely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution might be to utilize some information given to us in the [Facebook application security documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/#facebook_scraper). As of August 2012, Facebook lists these IP addresses as the ones their servers use to hit external sites :

```
31.13.24.0/21
31.13.64.0/18
66.220.144.0/20
69.63.176.0/20
69.171.224.0/19
74.119.76.0/22
103.4.96.0/22
173.252.64.0/18
204.15.20.0/22

2401:db00::/32
2620:0:1c00::/40
2a03:2880::/32
```

To get an updated list, you can user this command -

```
whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934' | grep ^route
```

So you would use some code similar to this PHP version -

```
if(in_array($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],$arrayOfIPAddresses) === TRUE){
  // current request is coming from Facebook's IP
}else{
  // current request is not from Facebook
}
```

Comment: Made a quick script to generate an htaccess that does simple auth except FB crawlers in case it's helpful for anyone. FB says they shift the crawler IPs, so you'd want to do cron this to regenerate the htaccess every so often https://gist.github.com/xenotropic/9d4570cfa956553166c8665ba34a8e08

Answer (score 1):

This solution depends on how important your basic authentication method is to you. You have accurately identified your problem though - indeed pages requiring a password can not be accessed by Facebook's servers.

You seem to be willing to disable this password authentication and it makes me believe that it's purpose is simply to *obfuscate* access to a staging server rather than secure it.  If this is true then there are some simple ways to allow Facebook's servers to access the data while still requiring the average user arriving at your page (possibly by accident) to enter a password. One such method would be to inspect the user agent being sent with the request -

An example in PHP -

```
if(stristr($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],'facebook') === FALSE){
  // require password
}else{
  // allow request with user agent containing Facebook  
}
```

Now it must be said here that user agent strings can be spoofed/forged and should not be considered accurate enough to be trusted 100%.